# MS Access Requery not working on MySQL->Oracle migration

Tags: mysql, oracle, ms-access, odbc

We have a MS access front end and a MySQL backend.
When we requery with the MySQL backend, everything works.
When we requery with the Oracle frontend, the requery doesn't seem to happen...nothing is refreshed...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show some code. Doesn't seem like this is an Access question.

Comment: I would assume you mean "Oracle _backend_" instead of frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how the Access DB is accessing the backend? I'm venturing a wild guess that there is some caching going on in the "ODBC" driver. MySQL typically uses autocommit, while the Oracle default would be to use transactions (but can typically be configured in the driver). Try issuing a commit (or rollback) before the requery and see if that changes anything.